# Stream screen to TV via network, miracast or vmware horizon?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vmware, streaming, tv

We're a hospital and using VMware Horizon to garant our employees access to their personal desktops from any client in the campus. There are:

- **A** *thin clients* running a kiosk version of Windows 10 1709
- **B** *thin clients* running IGEL LX 10
- **C** *fat clients* running a full installation of Windows 10 1709 + VMware Horizon Client.

In our meeting rooms are Sony FW-55BZ35F (smarttv with Android) with Apple TV 4K (mirror screen from iOS/macOS), Microsoft Miracast Adapter (mirror screen from Windows clients) installed. TV, Apple TV and Clients are all through cable or wifi connected to the network. On a daily basis our employees are using Onyx Venus-223 with option **A** installed and connect to the TVs through miracast.

**The problem** now is, that miracast ist only available on Windows and we need an alternative under IGEL Linux, because we want to change to IGEL.

---

**Our Idea** was to contact IGEL and ask them to implement [Wireless Display Software For Linux OS (WDS)](https://github.com/intel/wds) for their distribution. Another idea would be to use [AirParrot 2](https://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/) through Apple TV.

Since we're using VMware Horizon, is there a way to stream or mirror your current screen (running on fat/thin client) to a client hooked up our TV?

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux you may cast the screen to Chromecast using the Chrome browser.

See the article
[Casting a Chrome tab or entire desktop](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3228332?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB).